# /.byfn bring down consists of warning message

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

From [Hyperledger tutorial](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/build_network.html), byfn.sh tool to disconnect the network peers from hyperledger network

```
$ ./byfn.sh -m down
```

It show following warning messages:

```
WARNING: Network net_byfn not found.
Removing volume net_peer0.org2.example.com
WARNING: Volume net_peer0.org2.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_peer1.org2.example.com
WARNING: Volume net_peer1.org2.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_peer1.org1.example.com
WARNING: Volume net_peer1.org1.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_peer0.org1.example.com
WARNING: Volume net_peer0.org1.example.com not found.
Removing volume net_orderer.example.com
WARNING: Volume net_orderer.example.com not found.
```

I wonder about the message whether it could lead to an error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem ... there was actually an extra line in `byfn.sh` which results in calling `docker-compose down` twice.  The issue has been resolved in the master branch but was never backported to the release-1.1 branch.